# Search a list of names and categorizing each letter type

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to index a large list of names using ES.
I want to distinguish between consonants and vowels in each word, and be able to search based on the position of each letter and if it is a consonant or a vowel.

So say the name like:

`JOHN`

I want to enter this:

`CVCC`

and when I run the search, `JOHN` should be in the result set.

Is it possible somehow to index names in elastic search such that I could index and then search them using the tokens C and V for vowel?

So somehow Elasticsearch will have to index the character types for each position for each word, how can this be done?

Comment: Do you also want to keep the uppercase/lowercase matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `pattern_replace` char filters in a custom analyzer. Also, in my solution I have used a sub-field for the custom analyzer, thinking maybe that you will want other kinds of searches on the name field, the consonants-vowels one being only one of them.

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "replace_filter_lowercase_CONS",
            "replace_filter_uppercase_CONS",
            "replace_filter_lowercase_VOW",
            "replace_filter_uppercase_VOW"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "replace_filter_lowercase_CONS": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{1}",
          "replacement": "c"
        },
        "replace_filter_uppercase_CONS": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{1}",
          "replacement": "C"
        },
        "replace_filter_lowercase_VOW": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[aeiou]{1}",
          "replacement": "v"
        },
        "replace_filter_uppercase_VOW": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[AEIOU]{1}",
          "replacement": "V"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "cons_vow": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/test/1
{"name":"JOHN"}
POST /test/test/2
{"name":"Andrew"}
POST /test/test/3
{"name":"JOhn DOE"}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.cons_vow": {
        "value": "CVCC"
      }
    }
  }
}
```